# I am struggling to get this simple ASP login working, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am creating a new database with a web front end at work and one of the requirements was a login page. I found a simple page online and thought it looked good and would do the trick. I am struggling to get the it working correctly, if the username and password are correct it will go to the page I want it to. If I enter either of them incorrect it goes to a blank page. If I change the action of the form, it won't go to any page. The action on the form points it to the blank page if either the username or password are incorrect. Please see the code below:

Form

```
<!-- #include file="inc.head.asp" -->
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<h1><i>Login</i></h1>
<div id="displayBox" style="border: 3px solid #9C9595; height: 245px; width: 300px" class="blackBox">

<form name="myForm" action="login.asp" method="post">
<h3>Username: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="username" size="30"></h3>
<h3>Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" size="30"></h3>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
<br>
<p> If you want to request a new mobile phone, please click on the link below. </p>
<br>
<br>
<a href="newRequestHome.asp"><img src="images\nav_MobilephoneBigger.png"></a>
</form>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Login credentials

```
<%
response.buffer=true

Dim username
Dim password

username=request.form("username")
password=request.form("password")

if username="" then 
if password="" then 
response.redirect("page.index.asp")
else
response.redirect("loginFail.asp")
response.write("Please Enter a Valid Username and Password")
end if 
end if 
%>
```

As I mentioned, I found this online and I have tried to tailor it to what I need. I have removed the username and password because they are to do with the company I work for and do not want to that be put out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like

```
 if username="" or password="" then 
   response.redirect("page.index.asp")
else
   response.redirect("loginFail.asp")
   response.write("Please Enter a Valid Username and Password")
end if
```